# how to detect bitlock encrypted thumbdrive on a non-Windows OS?

Tags: encryption, filesystems

I have a thumbdrive that has been encrypted by Bitlock in Win7.
When the thumbdrive is plugged into a non-Windows machine, for instance Linux, it appears that the disk is full: no free space is available.
Is there a way to tell if a thumbdrive, or a harddisk, is encrypted by Bitlock?

My guess is that there is a header or flag in the filesystem with which we could check if the storage media has been encrypted by Bitlock.

Any thoughts/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

with kind regards,
Justin

---

with some investigation i seems to get the idea:
Bitlock encrypts the disk by packing everything into several data files, including existing files, and the empty space of the disk. it also put an autorun.inf onto the disk, which will invoke the BitLockerToGo.exe to prompt the user to enter the password/key. after that my guess is Bitlocker decrypts the data files so that we could access it as normal, not sure though.
anyway, a not-so-good solution is to check if you can find the autorun.inf, Bitlocker.exe and other related files on the disk, if yes, you will be able to tell the disk has been encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

The idea with encrypted volumes is that they are encrypted in whole and take all space available on the medium. Moreover, amount of free space of such volume is also a secret, so unless you can decrypt the volume you should not be able to determine *anything* about the encrypted disk, including the fact that it's encrypted with something.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, when the thumb drive is plugged into a Win7 machine, the OS is able to tell that the disk is encrypted and asks for password/keys. How could windows know it has been encrypted? Again I believe there is something that can be read from the storage media and determine if the media has been encrypted or not. Any thoughts?